# How do I use jQuery .when() function with a dynamic set of ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm using JqGrid and for each row in the grid I'm loading, I am making an ajax call to get additional data.

Once that's all complete, I need to apply some formatting.

I would like to use $.when(), but I'm not sure how to call it. I was researching the apply() method, but I still don't see how to use it appropriately.

Here is my code:

```
 $(rows).each(function () {
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: url,
                            data: data,
                            success: function (result) {

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });

   $.when(**What do i pass here??**).done(function () {

                    });
```

I had tried pushing each $.ajax call to an array, but I can't pass the array directly, and call everything.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may not work at all, in fact I'm curious as to whether or not it will. Try building the array of promise objects, then call `$.when.apply(null, arr).done(function () { ... });`

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) allows you to trigger a function and pass an array of arguments dynamically, such as in this case.

Comment: That's what I was trying, but apply doesn't return a jquery object, right? So the .done() won't be defined. I'm in the process of testing that now.

Comment: Calling `apply` should return whatever the function being triggered would return. Again, I'm not sure if the context (where I passed in `null`) is important. You could try `$` in place of `null`.

Comment: Also, how do I get the promise objects? If I wrap each ajax call in a push to an array, I get all the ajax objects, but they don't execute...

Comment: `var promise = $.ajax({ ... }); arr.push(promise);`

Comment: Wow, that's a nice way to use apply. I though apply was only to define the context of a function. Thanks!